# counter_cache for multi level association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models: `Topic`, `Post`, `Link`.

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links
  belongs_to :topic
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I'd like to have `counter_cache` for forums on `Link` model.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [counter_culture gem](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture).

From the [readme](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sub_category
  counter_culture [:sub_category, :category]
end

class SubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_categories
end
```

In the above example, the `Category` model will keep an up-to-date counter-cache in the `products_count` column of the `categories table`.